# Why is my roblox avatar looking like this in blender

Tags: import

For some reason when I import my avatar from ROBLOX to blender it looks like this? Does anyone know how to fix it . here is a before and after pic[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Can you, for exam?ple point out exactly what's wrong with the import, from your point of view?

Comment: The the antlers/horns look different and it looks like the legs and the face has a glow effect that is missing in Blender, right? Try the *Emission* input of the *PrincipledBSDF*... (just a guess because we cannot see your shader in Blender.)